# what's the solution here when it says Target class [SiteController] does not exist.?

Tags: php, laravel

i'm using laravel 9.don't know why it says "Target class [SiteController] does not exist".
**SiteController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
   public function home(){
        return "i am from siteController home";
    }

   public function about(){
        return "i am from siteController about";
    }

   public function contact(){
        return "i am from siteController contact";
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/', 'SiteController@home');

Route::get('/about', 'SiteController@about');

Route::get('/contact', 'SiteController@contact');
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Laravel version 8, controller route definitions must be defined using [standard PHP callable syntax](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-parameters):

[Basic Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers)

```
use App\Http\Controllers\SiteController;

Route::get('/', [SiteController::class, 'home']);
Route::get('/about', [SiteController::class, 'about']);
Route::get('/contact', [SiteController::class, 'contact']);
```

You may use the route:clear command to clear the route cache:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Comment: thanks a lot.i've followed your solution and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Please run the command, I think some cache has occured.

php artisan config:cache

php artisan optimize:clear